# How do I fix Travis CI when it says Failed to install -13.7.0. Remote repository may not be reachable

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, travis-ci, nvm

I'm trying to get a basic JS project running through Travis CI, but it always errors.

Looking at the job log, it doesn't seem to be able to install the version of Node I have set when it runs NVM install.

I've tried changing the version and checked that it's remotely available using the nvm ls-remote command.

I've also tried setting -node, so it just goes for the latest version, but that has the same issue.

here is the job log:

[image]

and here is the config

[image]

How do I get Travis CI to be able to run nvm install -13.7.0 successfully?  Is there something in the config that's wrong or should I be looking elsewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Installing a negative version number? Should it be ~?

Comment: Thanks.  I gave that a try, but the outcome is the same.  However, you were on the right track.  Version syntax needed to be "13.7.0".  It's strange because in the Travis documentation (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/)  says the syntax should have a space between the - and the version number. So it would look like this - 13.7.0  But Travis doesn't recognise that format.  If you use it, Travis, simply won't run. It also fails a yml linter check which was why I moved the - across and unknowingly created a negative version number.  Thanks again for the guidance.

Comment: The hyphen denotes a list item in YAML. You're using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when Travis can't download the node version because the NodeJS download server is down or unavailable.

Try hitting https://nodejs.org/download/ and check if it is up. If not, try the build process again once it becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

use the following format in you YML file to indicate node version:

```
node_js: 12.16.1
```

do not use "" to indicate the version.

Answer (score -1):

Version syntax needed to be "13.7.0" not - 13.7.0 as sugested here (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/), -13.7.0 or ~13.7.0.